# error handling in Freemarker

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, jboss, freemarker

I wrote my own class that implements TemplateExceptionHandler. That class will set error status in the response and then in my js, ajax call will enter in the error: part and show a message.

So in my TemplateExceptionHandler I have:

```
    String message = "my error msg";

    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    // set the message in response
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(message);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException in printMessage : " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Everything is working fine except that when I do

```
    response.getWriter();
```

depending on the part of the freemarker where the exception occured, there is already a html string. For exemple if in my freemarker I had

```
   <div class="testDiv">${unexistingVariable}</div>
```

when I execute

```
   out = response.getWriter();
   out.print(message);
```

in my response I will find

```
<div class="testDiv">my error msg
```

And a user will see this div in the error message since in my .js I have

```
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ...
            contentDialog.html(jqXHR.responseText);
```

Can you tell me why my response.getWriter() is already filled with the code that was processed until the exception occurred and how can I instantiate a clean response object with only my error message inside?

Thank you

Comment: In `handleTemplateException` method there is `Writer out` parameter. Why don't you use that?

Comment: Because I must pass by response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST); in order to enter to the generic error: part of my js that is constructing generic error dialog for the client.

Comment: It's already filled with code that was processed because there is already code that's been processed. You could try `response.reset()`, but whether or not that works would depend if any data has been sent yet.

Comment: reset after initialization helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent semi-finished pages to be sent back to the client, you have to use full-page buffering. This is independent of FreeMarker error handling, or even of FreeMarker (it just blindly writes into whatever `Writer` you pass to `Template.process`).

Also, are you sure you need a *FreeMarker* template exception handler for this? `Template.process` throws and exception when an error in a template occurs, so you could handle that like any other exception that occurs outside FreeMarker. The main purpose of `TemplateExceptionHandler`-s is to include the error information in the output (like for debugging), or to suppress certain errors. So if you don't want anything like these, just catch the exception outside FreeMarker (and then you may use `TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER` for the sake of clarity).

Comment: I wanted to avoid to catch all the exceptions in the actions try{}catch (Exception) because some developers forget to catch Exception in all of the existing actions. Thats why I thought to add one global case that will be executed every time.

Comment: In most apps you aren't supposed to catch exceptions in (most) *actions*. Usually you just let them bubble up until the framework logs them, rolls back transaction, resets response, generates HTTP 500. The situation is not different with template exceptions; it's just an exception like any other, so probably you shouldn't catch it around `template.process`. Also, an action should not call `template.process` directly, as that's the duty of the MVC framework, so you do it at only one place.

Comment: I agree with you, thing is that default exception handling with struts is a ugly popup window with exception stack shown to the user. I need something very specific, all the actions are called via ajax and all the responses with error status in them are treated by generic error: ajax function. So for every exception in my framework I need to set a error status and a specific message into the response. I created my specific ExceptionMappingInterceptor, and now all the exceptions are passing by this class. java exceptions are treated well (i enter in jquery ajax error: part)

Comment: but freemarker exceptions are not passed by this error: part of the ajax function(i dont understand why are they different)

Comment: Maybe the fastest way of finding out these thins is debugging Struts, see how it deals with the View part... And if Struts shows a stack trace *in production mode* to the user, then it's broken. (If you mean the yellow-red thing, that's FreeMarker's HTML_DEBUG error handler, but nobody should ever use that in production mode. It's for debugging, as the name implies. But it still re-throws the exception after printing the trace.)